# Whether there is any benefit of separating data/log files, setting fill factor, index rebuild/reorganize in a SAN storage?

Tags: sql-server, san

Let's assume that my storage is a SAN. This means it contains multiple disks. Even though we have logical drives configured, essentially everything - including the OS, SQL Server, and applications - all run on the same SAN, which means the data on the disk is highly fragmented.

So I want to ask: Is there any benefit when applying any of the following when the storage is SAN based?

1. Separating data/log files
2. Setting fill factor
3. Index rebuild/reorganize

Answer (score 2):

No.

1. No: [Separating data/log files](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/separating-data-log-files-make-server-reliable/)
2. No: [Setting fill factor](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/02/meme-week-setting-fill-factor-to-fix-fragmentation/)
3. No: [Index rebuild/reorganize](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/)

The only thing you can improve if you are using **HDD** on your SAN is moving to **SSD**.